# JQuery preflight request CORS

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cors

I am writing a web map and try to get fetch a JSON from a web ressource I do have credentials for. This works great in Python running via a JuPyteR notebook:

```
import requests
header = {  "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Language": "de-DE",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Origin": "https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net"}
}
dataJSON = json.dumps({ "username": "XXX",
    "password": "XXX"}).encode('utf8')
url = "URL/v1/token"
r = requests.post(url, data=dataJSON, headers=header)
```

The request from python gives the following header:

```
'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1', 
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 
'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'Accept-Language': 'de-DE', 
'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
'Content-Length': '67',
'Origin': 'https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net'
```

Now I am trying to recreate this in JavaScript to get data in my webmap:

```
$.ajax ({
          method: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({ "username": name,
    "password": pass}),
    headers:  {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Accept-Language": "de-DE",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
      },
          dataType:'json',
          url:'URL/v1/token',
          error: function() {
            alert("Login failed. Check username/password!");
          },
          success: function(resp) {

            token=resp.token;
          }
```

The console shows the following header for the preflight Options call:

```
Host: "cool API"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-DE
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control,content-type,pragma
Origin: https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The preflight Options response from the server is successfull in terms of a 200 response. Yet I don't get the POST finished as the console in FF and Chrome gives me:

```
Origin https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
```

The response header from the Server gives me:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 08:07:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: cache-control,content-type,pragma
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As the whole idea works in Python I hope I can "mimicri" the behaviour in Javascript/Jquery as well. So I am looking for your remarks/hints.

Note: The whole thing works in JS when running on Chrome using a CORS plugin...

Comment: Show your server CORS configuration - it looks like there is problem (in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null` )

Comment: then it shouldn't work in python on my local as well, should it?

Comment: it depends... on what is your origin for request's from python - the difference must be there

Comment: changed post for clarity

Comment: you show your ajax RESPONSE headers, but show your ajax REQUEST headers (chrome> console> networks> your request)

Comment: and also: Show your server CORS configuration

Comment: It's not my server, I just have credentials for the API

Comment: Do your `python` send request from your local machine - the same from which your ajax send request. If yes - where in your python you set: `'Origin': 'https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net'`

Comment: Your python `'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'`, is different than your ajax POST `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` - this also can cause problem

Comment: yes, as stated the ajax post request header is not shown in the network monitor as ajax creates a preflight request. The request header for this is shown here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183893/discussion-between-riccardo-and-kamil-kielczewski).

Answer (score 2):

Python does not check CORS and the browser does to avoid security issues like XSS,

You need to make the server respond the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with the domain from what the endpoint is being called ("https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net" ?)

If you want the server to allow being called for any domain use:

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

( currently is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null" )

This is needed because the browser needs to know if that server expect to be called from that domain.

Answer (score 2):

CORS rules are primarily enforced by the client, not by the server. You python script does not implement these rules, hence the request succeeds, but your browser *does* implement them and blocks the request.

Now the server is supposed to provide information to the client about whether to allow the CORS request. The preflight request is just there to obtain this information (since your request is not a "simple request", cf [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)). In your case, clearly the server is not well configured:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
```

You should have "*" instead of null, or at least "https://myCoolServer.azurewebsites.net".